# Stingray being used on device remotely, my screen shows activity without my input I want to alert device when this is happening

Tags: action, connection-string, root, imei, stingray

I want to know when my phone is being used remotely by a stingray looking around in device I see it on screen when looking but when it's sitting idle and I'm not looking and phone is black screen but use or activity  not normal to background happening I should be able to send alert ring alarm on device suspicious activity a stingray actually data mining my device either man in middle or duel sim my device remotely

I am just starting this project I will build on Android 13 os rooted device 5g network incoming connection or 2g from stingray to device when I make incoming connection to device I want to notify user of device activity either incoming connection activity or device use not normal without human input with alert on device.